# Quirky Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing something wrong but **WHAT!**  I've looked over it a hundred times.  For some reason, it isn't retrieving the object from the document.  Here is my index and Javascript source:

```
var blinkOn =false;
var blinkObj=document.getElementById("blink");
function blinkCursor() {
    if (blinkOn) 
        {   
            blinkObj.style.display="none";
        } else {
            blinkObj.style.display="inline";
        }
    blinkOn=!blinkOn;
    setTimeout("blinkCursor()",500);    
}

blinkCursor();
```

INDEX:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            CMD.exe
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cmd.css" />
        <script language="JavaScript" SRC="cmd.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="content">&gt;</span><span style="display:none;" id="blink"  >|</span>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be so much help!  (well.. wait... duh :p )

Comment: Is your javascript placed at the head of your page? Because you may be calling it before the element has been loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your JavaScript is executing before the HTML is interpreted - the DOM has not loaded.

While I'd recommend that you use something like jQuery to ensure document readiness, here's your problem solved without it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function blinkCursor() {
            var blinkObj=document.getElementById("blink");
            blinkObj.style.display = (blinkObj.style.display == "none")? "inline" : "none";
            setTimeout("blinkCursor()",500);
        }
        setTimeout("blinkCursor()",500);    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to either use an `onload` event or put the script inline in the body, and after the element. This is because when Javascript in the `<head>` is loaded, the full DOM isn't available yet, so it can't see elements.

Comment: As a workaround -- just move script tag in the last position before body closing tag. But it`s ugly-n-dirty (you know).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting the element in the global scope, grab a reference within the function.  This prevents the function from failing if it is called when the element doesn't exist.

You could also call this from body::`onLoad`/`onDomReady` instead, depending on framework/preference.

```
function blinkCursor() {
    var blinkObj=document.getElementById("blink");
    if (blinkObj) {
        blinkObj.style.display=(blinkObj.style.display == "none") ? 'inline' : 'none';
    }
}
function stopBlink() {
    clearInterval(blinkInterval);
}
var blinkInterval = setInterval(blinkCursor, 500);
```

Also, don't pass `setTimeout`/`setInterval` a string, pass it a reference to the function instead.

Comment: And use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` (obviously it only needs to be run once)